# Stop Camera Capture EmguCV

Tags: opencv, c++-cli, emgucv

How do I stop a camera capture in EmguCV 2.X and ensure that I have no connection to the camera in my application anymore.

There does not seem to be a release() function like there is in OpenCV.

Relevant parts of code:

Capture Definition:

```
Emgu::CV::Capture^ capture; // Creates a capture object
```

On Start Button Click:

```
capture = gcnew Emgu::CV::Capture(_CameraIndex); //create a camera capture
```

If I add the following after initialisation:

```
capture.Dispose(); //To stop and call Garbage Collector
```

Then it gives me the following error:

```
Dispose is not a member of Emgu::CV::Capture
```

Comment: Call the `Dispose()` function. http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.2.0/document/html/a3fc8f4c-5172-d440-1e10-093bc946806a.htm

Comment: Dispose doesn't seem to be a member of the Capture class..

Comment: if you develop with c++ why don't you use opencv? if you develop on .net platform then why don't you use C#?

Comment: @cagri Because C++CLI is neither C++ or C#...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's safe to delete the object, which calls the destructor, and in turn `Dispose()`. You can change it to `if (capture != nullptr) delete capture;`.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that whilst Dispose is not a method I can just `delete` the object and then reinitialise it

```
capture = gcnew Emgu::CV::Capture(cameraIndex);
delete capture;
capture = gcnew Emgu::CV::Capture(cameraIndex);
```

AFAIK there is nothing inherently dangerous with doing this but I am not 100%